# prevent overwriting file if already exists using installshield2009

Tags: installshield, installshield-2009

While installing application i want to prevent overwriting my DB file if it already exists at specified location.
As i am new to using installshield could any please guide.
Tried setting Never Overwrite property of component to true but didn't work in my case, it's still overwriting my DB file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that Always overwrite property is set to checked on file level, you can check that by right clicking on db file under component and then click on property menu.
If it turns out to be checked then set it to unchecked.